# lxml equivalent to BeautifulSoup "OR" syntax?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm converting some html parsing code from BeautifulSoup to lxml.  I'm trying to figure out the lxml equivalent syntax for the following BeautifullSoup statement:

```
soup.find('a', {'class': ['current zzt', 'zzt']})
```

Basically I want to find all of the "a" tags in the document that have a class attribute of either "current zzt" or "zzt".  BeautifulSoup allows one to pass in a list, dictionary, or even a regular express to perform the match.

What is the lxml equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the xpath expr should be: `//a[@class='current zzt' or @class='zzt'`

Comment: (it's missing a ] at the end)

Comment: That works- but it returns a list (like findall() would).  Any way to make it behave more like find()? (Without just tacking a [0] on the end?)

Comment: class = 'current zzt' is not a single class.  It's two classes.  Do you mean that you want to find all links with either the 'zzt' class or both the 'current' and 'zzt' classes?

Comment: @endolith:  I want to find all of the links where class="current zzt" OR class="zzt".  So it either has bot togeather or just "zzt".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, lxml does not provide the "find first or return None" method you're looking for. Just use `(select(soup) or [None])[0]` if you need that, or write a function to do it for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lxml.html
import lxml.cssselect
soup = lxml.html.fromstring("""
        <html>
        <a href="foo" class="yyy zzz" />
        <a href="bar" class="yyy" />
        <a href="baz" class="zzz" />
        <a href="quux" class="zzz yyy" />
        <a href="warble" class="qqq" />
        <p class="yyy zzz">Hello</p>
        </html>""")

select = lxml.cssselect.CSSSelector("a.yyy.zzz, a.yyy")
print [lxml.html.tostring(s).strip() for s in select(soup)]
print (select(soup) or [None])[0]
```

Ok, so `soup.find('a')` would indeed find first a element or None as you expect. Trouble is, it doesn't appear to support the rich XPath syntax needed for CSSSelector.